# How Union behaves in SQL query (in terms of priority)

Tags: sql

We know that in SQL the order the code is executed is:

1. `FROM`
2. `WHERE`
3. `GROUP`
4. `SELECT`

Now, in SQL I can write (*Example1*):

```
SELECT colA, colB
FROM tableA
UNION
SELECT colA, colB
FROM tableB
WHERE colA > 1
```

and I can also write (*Example2*):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT colA, colB
  FROM tableA
  UNION
  SELECT colX, colA
  FROM tableB
)
WHERE colA > 1
```

My question is about *Example1*: the `WHERE` condition is on `tableB` or on the `UNION` of `tableA` and `tableB`? Unlike *Example2*, where it's very clear, in *Example1* it's not (?).

I didn't find any documentation in any DB that explains this about the `UNION`.

Comment: what is clear in example2?

Comment: @mangusta The WHERE is on the result of the union due to the brackets

Comment: I doubt whether the example 1 will run or not without giving aliases. It will say something like colA in the query is ambiguous.

Comment: how do you know it is on the result of union? the presence of brackets does not necessarily guarantee that

Comment: @mangusta WHERE clause is done after FROM

Comment: no, it depends on the execution plan. have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437507/union-with-where-clause/5439460. in this example, the filters are applied prior to union, although union is in brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To re-cap the diagrams below, keeping it simple:*

A *query_block* has no set operator (e.g. `UNION`) and no `ORDER BY`. The `WHERE` clause applies at this level:

```
[WITH ...] SELECT ... FROM ... [WHERE ...] [GROUP BY ... [HAVING ...]]
```

A *subquery* is one or more *query_blocks* separated by set operators, with optional `ORDER BY`. The ordering applies after the set operators:

```
query_block [UNION query_block]* [ORDER BY ...]
```

So to answer your question: In Example1, **the `WHERE` condition is on `tableB`**.

---

The diagrams in the [Oracle 12c Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2065706) shows it pretty good:

***select::=***
[image: select]

***subquery::=***
[image: subquery]

***query_block::=***
[image: query_block]

Answer (score 1):

The `WHERE` clause as written in the first statement belongs to the second part of the UNION. You can test this by using different column names in the two tables:

```
create table t1 (c1 int, c2 int);
create table t2 (c3 int, c4 int);
```

Then the following query:

```
select c1, c2 
from t1
union all
select c3, c4
from t2
where c1 > 1
```

will result in an error claiming that the column `c1` does not exist (or can't be used in that context - depending on the DBMS product).

The same rule applies to a `GROUP BY` or `HAVING`, but **not** to a possible `ORDER BY` - that always sorts the result of the union.

[Postgres example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ae4bc3a1db95ce05a20888dbeb320a2d)

[Oracle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ae4bc3a1db95ce05a20888dbeb320a2d)

[SQL Server example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ae4bc3a1db95ce05a20888dbeb320a2d)

Answer (score 0):

Hi @HaloKu Have you tested it ? I believe that a small test would give an answer to your question...

Please check this [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7234edfe18bb775af3a14a0935f7949d).

You can see that for the Example 1, the where clause will influence only the tableB.
The example is for Oracle Database. Please can you give us the information what database do you use?

Here is the TEST for MySQL: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=62675070b512ba4441603bdef2b9b771
It acts the same way as Oracle does...

Also, please check this question here: [UNION with WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437507/union-with-where-clause/5439460)

Comment: This is exactly my question. Is this behavior DB specific? Should I expect diffrent behavior in Presto or MySQL? Is it part of Native SQL defintion or not?

Comment: What part exactly. You only asked "The WHERE condition is on tableB or on the union of tableA and tableB?". And I answered that already... I can update my answer for MySQL also but what is there that is giving you a problem?